# PHP XML Extract data out of the tag or field

Tags: php, xml

I know how to extract the data from between two tags or elements but I do not know how to extract the data from within the element itself for example (see this section **Tax="0.0" EHF="0.0" Freight="0.0" Handling="0.0" SubTotal="0.72"**). Any help would be most appreciated.

```
<INVTOTAL Tax="0.0" EHF="0.0" Freight="0.0" Handling="0.0" SubTotal="0.72">0.72</INVTOTAL>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do it. For example, using xpath, something like

```
$invoice= '
<root><INVTOTAL Tax="10.0" EHF="0.0" Freight="0.0" Handling="0.0" SubTotal="0.72">0.72</INVTOTAL></root>';
$XMLDoc = new DOMDocument();
$XMLDoc->loadXML($invoice);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($XMLDoc);

$tax = $xpath->query("//INVTOTAL/@Tax");
echo($tax[0]->nodeValue);
```

Output:

```
10.0
```